# Sharing a custom view as an image in iOS

Tags: ios, tableview, share, uigraphicscontext

I have a tableview with custom cells that collapse and display details on a tap. There are more cells than can be displayed at a time on the screen. I want to create a custom `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` that has the header of the screen (an image with the logo of my app) and all the cells in the tableview displaying the details underneath and then share it using the share button.

I tried finding examples but was unable to find anything that helps. How can I achieve this result?

Here is an example of what I am looking for:

[image: Tableview UIGraphicsContext with all custom cells showing]